# Intercepting FetchBackend's fetch requests to add an authorisation header

Tags: angular

Is there any way to intercept FetchBackend's fetch request to add an authorisation header ?

I have tried intercepting these fetch requests using an HttpInterceptor but it doesn't seem to work since the FetchBackend doesn't use the HttpClient interface

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the FetchBackend, you likely have `provideHttpClient(withFetch())` in your providers.

You should not be using the FetchBackend directly but the HttpClient (which will rely on the FetchBackend when enabled via `withFetch()`.

```
constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  const url = 'http://localhost:8080/sse';
  let sseRequest: HttpRequest<any> = new HttpRequest('GET', url, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  });
  httpClient.request(sseRequest)
}
```

If you want to set an interceptor:

```
export const authenticationInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next:
  HttpHandlerFn) => {
     const userToken = 'MY_TOKEN'; const modifiedReq = req.clone({
       headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${userToken}`),
     });
 
     return next(modifiedReq);
};
```

Which can be used as `provideHttpClient(withFetch(), withInterceptors([authenticationInterceptor]))`

Comment: Hello :)
This doesn't seem to intercept fetch requests. Here's the link to a sample app with the solution that you suggested : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-g33ciz?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Please  see my edit, you should not be using the FetchBackend directly !

Comment: I don't think I can view your changes directly in my project. Can you please send me the link to the project you forked ?

Comment: Thank you @MatthieuRiegler ! It does work as intended :)